# nominatim (OSM) does not pick up the address

Tags: java, geolocation, openstreetmap, nominatim

I've made this Java program to pick up an address from nominatim, but I get an empty result in return. Is there an error in the code ?

```
String address = "Ctra. Ibiza a San Antonio, Km 5, 07816 San Rafael, Illes Balears, Spain";

StringBuilder urlStringConnection = new StringBuilder();

urlStringConnection.append  ("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/");
urlStringConnection.append  (ESAPI.encoder().encodeForURL(address));
urlStringConnection.append  ("?format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1");

URL url = new URL(urlStringConnection.toString());
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection ();
uc.connect();
List<Place> places = (parseGeocodingAddress (uc.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: What is your question? The address or the address format is not known to Nominatim. Try to avoid abbreviations, try to avoid postcodes, check if the address is actually contained in OSM.

Comment: I thought the more info the better

Comment: Not necessarily. Nominatim tries to use *all* of the given information. If it can't handle some of the given parts it will fail. I heard [photon](http://photon.komoot.de/) to be more robust but I've never tried it.